# How to allow HTML entities in a single row in the DT package for R

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, escaping

I need to be able to use HTML entities in the first row of my DataTable. I would prefer to escape the rest of the table but `escape` argument only allows for the whole table or by column. Is there a workround?

```
m = matrix(c(
  '<b>Bold</b>', '<em>Emphasize</em>', '<a href="http://rstudio.com">RStudio</a>',
  '<a href="#" onclick="alert(\'Hello World\');">Hello</a>'
), 2)
colnames(m) = c('<span style="color:red">Column 1</span>', '<em>Column 2</em>')
datatable(m, escape = FALSE)
```

Outcome:
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdVGN.png)

Desired outcome:
[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5pS7.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide some data by using `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and posting the results.

Comment: Thank you, I have added some images and code from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/